# My nose is running when I'm exercising. Is it normal?

Tags: workout, health

I can't exercise without paper handkerchiefs at hand (perhaps, you would call them kleenexes, but for me, kleenexes and paper handkerchiefs are different things, the latter are thicker). Whenever I exercise, I use them to both mop my sweat and blow my nose (*<**warning!** graphic details!>* it's not that disgusting thick greenish substance that you have when you catch a cold, it's watery and fairly transparent; in fact, it's not much different from sweat *< the end of graphic details>*). Is it something unusual? Is it indicative of something? *<**warning!** more graphic details!>* Also, after a workout, I have to draw in from my nasopharynx and spit out thick lumps of snot mixed with saliva from my throat. *< the end of graphic details>* I want to stress out that I'm not ill or anything, as far as I'm aware. It's not something that started to occur only recently.

Comment: Are your workouts fairly intense?  Like HIIT or really long runs?

Comment: Yes, no, maybe? It might be, it might not. Mine does, but I know the reasons. This isn't really an answerable question.

Comment: @DeeV It's quite intensive but not very long (it takes approximately 65-70 minutes)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  My sinuses also clean out after long/intense workouts.  Just one of those gross things about exercise nobody really talks about.